# Transistor count of a shift register

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, shift-register

Static RAM requires, as I understand it, six transistors per bit.

How many transistors per bit are required for a shift register, of the simple serial in serial out variety? Is it likewise six transistors per bit, or can it be simpler because of the lack of requirement for random access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a shift register needs more transistors per bit because you need master-slave behavior like an edge-triggered flip-flop. In CMOS you can make a decent flip-flop with about 18 transistors: an inverter for the clock, four inverters for the latches, and four transmission gates for the latches.

You could pull the clock inverter out the flip-flops and go to a 2-phase design. If you need the register outputs to drive anything other than the next bit in the register then you might need a few transistors for a buffer in each bit. If you don't care about noise immunity and speed you could save a few transistors by using a single pass transistor instead of a full transmission gate.

For estimations, I would assume 24 transistors per bit.

Comment: Oh! In that case, would it not be cheaper to do the same job with an array of static RAM plus an incrementing address counter? What's the advantage of a shift register?

Comment: A shift register can execute a shift by one position in a single clock cycle. Using RAM would require two or three clock cycles **per position**. A RAM uses many transistors outside of each bit for address decoding, sense amplifiers, and so on. I don't know what you mean by "cheaper" but a RAM would probably require more transistors than a functionally equivalent shift register, unless your shift register was very, very large.

Comment: Dynamic shift registers are a thing, or were.  They used to be popular for short-term storage in computers in the 40's, 50's and 60's, because they use fewer active devices.  I'm not sure how many transistors it takes per bit, but the word "fewer" certainly comes to mind.

Comment: Datapoint introduced their first computers (sold as IBM terminal emulators, but really were independently programmable, still used in Europe today) using PMOS shift-registers as the main-memory. Datapoint went to Intel, seeking a lower-power solution; the Datapoint people ensured the Intel architecture would map onto the Datapoint compilers and assemblers without any problem. Thus the Intel registers and memory model comes from Datapoint Corporation of San Antonio.

Answer (score 1):

With a two clock phase structure, I believe a shift register could be implemented with latches instead M/S FF's.

00010001000100010001 clock 1 odd cells

01000100010001000100 clock 2 even cells